# Meaning of “But I repeat myself” in Mark Twain's quote?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is the following sentence in the conversation between Florentyna Rosnovski, the heroine of Jeffrey Archer’s novel, *The Prodigal Daughter*, who was first elected as the Congressman of Illinois and her husband, Richard Kane, Chairman of a New York bank.

> She captured the Ninth District of Illinois with a plurality of over 27,000 votes. Richard was the first to congratulate her.
>   "I’m proud of you, my darling." He smiled mischievously. "Mind you, I’m sure Mark
>   Twain would have been as well."
>   "Why Mark Twain?" asked Florentina, puzzled.
>   "Because it was he who said: *'Suppose you were an idiot and suppose you were a member of Congress.* ***But I repeat myself'***." – *The Prodigal Daughter*, Page 302.

I can’t get the idea of the last phrase, “But I repeat myself,” following the preceding subjunctives – Suppose you are idiot or a member of Congress. Is Richard simply saying “Whoever you are, I won’t change.”?

What is the meaning of it as the punch line of a famous quote from Mark Twain?

Is he saying he won’t change his attitudes / belief / way of life whoever the counterpart is, i.e. he always stays as he is? Though it may sound uncouth, what is the essence of the humor of this line?

Comment: The first time he say it "suppose you are an idiot". Then he repeats the same thing by saying "or a member of congress". The idea being that saying "a member of congress" is the same as saying "suppose you're an idiot".

Comment: @Joe. Sure. The title of the book is "The Prodigal Daughter."  It’s the switch of the episode of “The Prodigal son” appearing in the Gospel of Luke (Luke 15:11-32). I thought I put it "The Prodigal Daughter."

Comment: @Joe. Thanks for your pointing out "typo."

Comment: Suppose you are Jeffrey Archer and suppose you're a terrible author. But I repeat myself

Comment: Fred Shapiro, _The Yale Book of Quotations_ (2006) says that the quotation first appeared in Albert Paine, [_Mark Twain: A Biography_](https://books.google.com/books?id=FkcLAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA724&dq=%22Mark+Twain:+A+Biography%22+Paine+%22But+I+repeat+myself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqwMDDlcjRAhVNxWMKHZL2AmwQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Mark%20Twain%3A%20A%20Biography%22%20Paine%20%22But%20I%20repeat%20myself%22&f=false) (1912). There the quotation has this form: "Reader, suppose you were an idiot. And suppose you were a member of Congress. But I repeat myself."

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The joke is that Twain considers *idiot* and *member of Congress* to be synonymous!

Comment: Though, given Twain's opinion, Richard saying that Twain would be proud of Florentina for being elected to Congress makes no sense. I assume that's just Archer's clumsy segue to Twain's joke.

Comment: More gems by the same wit on the same subject [here](http://www.twainquotes.com/Congress.html).

Comment: @Gary Student. I understood that Mark Twain considered himself an idiot just like Congressmen are.
Then, what does “I repeat myself” mean? Is Twain saying “I repeat that myself is idiot too”?

Comment: And yet he surely doesn't think that all idiots are members of Congress, only the other way around (which makes them..not quite synonyms). It'd be like saying "Suppose you were a dog and suppose you were a black dog. But I repeat myself." Perhaps Twain made a minor mistake, and it would better (from a literal sense, perhaps not a humorous one) have been swapped to have said "Suppose you were a member of Congress and suppose you were an idiot."

Comment: @YoichiOishi Twain's joke isn't that he considers *himself* an idiot. The joke is his claim that "suppose you are an idiot" and "suppose you are a member of congress" are equivalent, i.e.: that to be a member of congress is to be an idiot. He is making fun of politicians through wordplay. (This is a traditional pastime in pretty much every social circle, including those of the politicians themselves.)

Comment: @YoichiOishi: *I repeat myself* means "I repeating what **I** said", as opposed to what someone else said: "I have said the same thing twice."

Comment: Consider myself spoiled.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: IOW, if you have already said that someone is an idiot then adding that the person is also a member of Congress would be redundant.

Comment: @StonyB. So “I” of “I repeat myself,” is Richard, not Mark Twain?  i.e. Mark Twain’s words are “Suppose you were an idiot and suppose you were a member of Congress,” which isn’t complete as a sentence, but “I repeat myself,” is Richard’s follow-up?

Comment: @YoichiOishi: Mark Twain's entire quote was: "Suppose you were an idiot, and suppose you were a member of Congress; but I repeat myself." The author's use of this brilliant quote is just sloppy writing, because he would be effectively insulting his wife, calling her an idiot according to Twain. And, Twain would not be proud of her; he didn't suffer fools. So it's simply a sloppy (and therefore confusing) choice of words. Not all written English is *well written*. (Please see my answer below.)

Comment: @TimS. That's a great point, one that I hadn't caught in my previous familiarity with the quote. But I thought about it even more now, and maybe Twain--in his genius level of exaggeration--was quite aware of what is implied by this ordering, and therefore *was* saying that all idiots are members of Congress, that is, that only Congressmen are so stupid as to actually achieve the rank of "idiot". (It's fun to think that he may have thought that, though I'd easily believe that his intuition for humor was what placed them in this order; it's the correct thing to do for the structure of the joke).

Comment: An alternative is that the usage "but I repeat myself" doesn't mean saying exactly the same thing again, but saying something superfluous that repeats information in something already said. At least that is how I have always used and understood the clause. If I were to say P and Q but (in some manifest sense) P = > Q I would be repeating myself. I neither think that Twain thought all idiots to be members of Congress or that what he said was an error.

Comment: @medica I don't think it's sloppy writing at all.  The husband was poking fun at his wife.  Depending on the relationship, that might be the norm for the couple.

Comment: @medica from the out of context snippet of the book in the question, the two reasonable interpretations I can make are that Richard is either teasing her with the Twain remark; or that his initial congratulations were joking/mocking and that he disapproves of what Florentina did.  Without having it the book I can't say if either of those fit with the remainder of the book.

Comment: @Chelonian Maybe it's just me, but a bit set theory makes the whole thing rather obvious. Although it is interesting, because the ordering actually changes the meaning from the expected (which many people seem to miss). Simplified: Let `P` be any person. `I(P)` means that P is an idiot. `C(P)` means P is a congressman. The statement is that given `I(P)` adding `C(P)` does not give us any new information. From this it follows that `I(P) -> C(P)` *must* be true, since that's the only way the added statement does not give us any new information.

Comment: cont. That also makes the statement by the husband interesting: One way to interpret it is that he's teasing her: Assuming she's an idiot, Twain would be proud of her getting elected, because that would prove his proposition true after all :-)

Comment: @Voo, enjoyed the set theory and, yes, I'd like to believe that is what Twain meant--that if you tell me that Pete is an idiot I can tell you *a priori* that he is a member of Congress.

Answer (score 19):

Mark twain's comment relies on the sarcastic use of [tautology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology):

> needless repetition of an idea, statement, or word.

The author Dan Brown mistakenly makes a lot of tautological statements, parodied in [this description](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/10049454/Dont-make-fun-of-renowned-Dan-Brown.html):

> The critics said his writing was clumsy, ungrammatical, *repetitive and repetitive*.

The last word is an unnecessary repetition of *repetitive* - a tautology.

What Mark Twain is saying is that to say *suppose someone is an idiot* and *suppose someone is a congresman* is a tautology: they are the same thing. (All Congressmen by his definition were idiots.) To say both is a tautology.

To be honest, the writing is poor in the section you quote, because Richard is basically saying that Mark Twain would have considered F. an *idiot*, which is not something Twain would have been proud of. So Richard either is insulting his wife, or he is really not making sense here, which might be why it's confusing.

It's just a way for the author to sneak in a brilliant quote without having to work for it. It's an example of sloppy writing.

Comment: Plus vote. I think yours is a reasonable and very helpful remark. It’s hard for anyone like me who have learnt English as the second language to parse the line to that depth. I was even unable to tell whether “But I repeat myself,' is Mark Twain’s or Richard Kane’s. Now it seems to be pretty clear to me. Many thanks.

Comment: I disagree with your appreciation of a confusing writing. The author makes it clear that Richard is being ironic, noting his *mischievous* smile. He is mocking his wife. This is further supported by the reaction of his wife, who looks puzzled, as she can't imagine why her husband would summon Mark Twain in this situation.

Comment: If that is so, I would not call this *ironic*, but rather, *passive aggressive*: "I'm proud of you, my darling. Mark Twain would call you an idiot." It's not even a back-handed compliment; it's a direct assault. Which makes no sense if he loves her. Maybe he doesn't. Maybe she's puzzled because she doesn't know the Twain quote. But I'm not going to read it to find out!

Comment: Yes, *passive aggressive* is absolutely correct. I didn't read the book but this excerpt gives a strong impression of aggressivity and envy from Richard.

Comment: Maybe he's trying to say (clumsily) that Twain would be glad she was raising the general intelligence level of Congress by joining?

Comment: Passive aggressive seems entirely wrong.  He's being overtly aggressive, to the extent that it's aggressive.  Passive aggressive would not be nearly so direct.  I think it would be hard to judge the specific effect of the statement without a full understanding of the characters involved (which I don't have), but I've known plenty of couples who enjoyed witty repartee of this sort.

Comment: @Joe - I really think we need more context to interpret it in the manner you have. My guess is that it's just bad writing.

Comment: "All Congressmen by his definition were idiots" - actually if we follow the logic that's wrong. If we follow the actual logic of the statement it implies that all idiots are Congressmen and *not* the opposite. I showed the slightly longer (although still informal) argument in the accepted answer, but basically: If adding a proposition `Y` to a statement `X` means you are repeating yourself, that means that `Y` doesn't add any new information to the existing statement (so `X` and `X ^ Y` are equivalent). That is only true if `X -> Y` but *not* if `Y -> X`.

Comment: @Voo - it really isn't that important. It's a joke. Three men walk into a bar. Wait, were they old men or young men? Was it a mix? *Does it really matter?* It's a *joke*.

Comment: "Which makes no sense if he loves her." -- you're not British, right? I don't think much of Jeffrey Archer, and certainly would not hold him up as a great representative of the country, but perhaps this passage would be of use to foreigners trying to understand British humour. The remark is snide, and quite possibly intended to make Richard seem a jerk, but is *well* within the bounds of British teasing. Perhaps the author's mistake is putting it in the mouth of an American in any context other than a sitcom, with a Chandler Bing-style "exaggerated sarcasm" intonation and canned laughter ;-)

Comment: I would interpret the husband's words as softly teasing or gently ribbing his wife, he wants to be sure that Florentyna doesn't get an over-inflated opinion of herself, a risk that can happen to anyone, irrespective of their sex when an important election is won.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - a perfectly reasonable assumption. However (why is there always a however?) from what I've seen of Archer's writing in previous questions, this is also a likely scenario: *Archer now having his protagonist win an election, thinks: "Hmm? I think I'll Google Great Quotes About Politicians. Here's a witty one! I think I'll work this one in right here." Does so awkwardly.*

Comment: I believe that Jeffrey Archer is erudite and witty enough to already have these quotes ready at a drop of a hat. Archer had started writing novels before Google became the phenomena it is now (she quickly rushes to Wikipedia to double check) EDIT I was right!