# Are all Congressmen idiots?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, quotes, logic

Really couldn't resist the question title :-)

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186116/meaning-of-but-i-repeat-myself-in-mark-twains-quote) question asks about the famous quote by Mark Twain:

```
Suppose you were an idiot and suppose you were a member of Congress. But I repeat myself.
```

which I'm sure most people here know. When I first read it I obviously interpreted the meaning as "All congressmen are idiots" - but when trying to actually reason through the construct in a comment for the question, that actually doesn't work out I find.

Let's go for a slight formalism with propositional logic:

- `I` means that the person is an idiot.
- `C` means that the person is a congressman.

Now Twain states that the person is an idiot so we know that `I` is true. Then he states  `C`. So far so good, `I ^ C`. But the next sentence is: "but I repeat myself" which I can only interpret as "but the second statement doesn't add any new information to the first". So this means that `I -> I ^ C` (since otherwise saying `C` is true would add information). This can be simplified to `not I v C` and since we know that `I` is true, this means that `C` must be true - nothing surprising there.

So now the options are: Did I make a mistake in my reasoning? Did Mark Twain screw up in his and actually wanted the opposite order or I guess #3 did Mark Twain really want to imply that every idiot is a congressman?

Comment: The [logic] tag doesn't license logic *notation*; this is English.SE after all. Could you explain what you actually mean, please? [You're wrong in your conclusion even though the question title is correct; he was implying that every Congressman was an idiot, but I've no idea how you have arrived at your conclusion.]

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU.

Comment: The part that he's repeating is that you're an idiot. The second part of the statement does add information; that's you're a congressman.

Comment: @Andrew Well if the actual reasoning given is correct (and if not someone would have to point out my flaw), he may have *wanted* to say that all Congressmen are idiots, but that's not what he actually *said*. The problem with language is that it can be rather hard to parse correctly, but basically: Saying "You are an idiot and a congressman, but I repeat myself" implies that being an idiot means one is a congressman. The opposite doesn't follow.

Comment: cont. Or to give a simpler example: "It just rained and the road is wet". Clearly if it has rained the road must be wet so the second part doesn't give us any new information. But just because the road is wet doesn't mean it just rained.. I could have just spilled some water after all.

Comment: I agree that you're correct. The proposition as written implies that all idiots are congressmen logically. Doesn't seem on topic for here though.

Comment: It's not possible to point out your flaw here because you have explained it in logical symbols. If you're going to do that, the question needs to be asked on Philosophy.SE which deals in pure logic. *Here* we deal in English.

Comment: @Martin Would that be better suited for philosophy SE or where would you put that into? Wasn't sure either where to put it. Anyhow just seemed a bit surprising to me that someone like Twain would make such a relatively simple mistake. Always striked me as someone pedantic about the meaning of words.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It isn't difficult. It is analogous to saying "suppose you were an animal and suppose you were a cat. But I repeat myself". Clearly this is not an exact repetition as not all animals are cats.

Comment: @Voo - I think you're reading too much into it. He's making a quick joke, that 'All congressmen are idiots'. That's all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I had them the wrong way round (despite my assertion about difficulty!) now fixed,

Comment: @Andrew So theoretical linguistics is off-topic here? I ended in a class in college on that in college (rather off-topic for my actual degree, but it was fun) and it seemed to deal with similar things when talking about semantics or possibly syntax. But I guess better to transfer this to philosophy. Just thought that people with more experience dealing with Twain could have some other point of view. But I guess even someone like Mark Twain would make a mistake once or twice, without anything deeper behind it.

Comment: @Voo The problem is not the logic: we have a [logic] tag. The problem is your use of logic symbols, specifically `->`, `^` and `v`.

Comment: What @dwjohnston: But if we want to defend the "validity" of the quip, we can always suppose that *"Suppose you were an idiot"* was the target of the implied charge (that something which was said added nothing to something else which was *also* said). By the time he gets to the word ***But***, the preceding sentence is just "there" - it's no longer a "process occurring over time". The "temporal" implications of ***repeat*** can reasonably be discarded in context.

Comment: @Voo Put in a key for the logic symbols!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about propositional logic, not English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fuller quotation is:

> Reader, suppose you were an idiot. And suppose you were a member of
>   Congress. But I repeat myself. Simply suppose you were a member of
>   Congress. And suppose you started-up what you believed to be your faculties, and worked out 
>   the draft of a law to cover the needs of some industry or other which you did not know 
>   anything about.

It is clear in context that the supposition Twain considered redundant was "you were an idiot", since that is the one he removes to simplify. So his intent is to state that all members of congress are idiots.

I don't believe that "I repeat myself" must be taken to mean "the second statement adds no new information". Rather, it means that the second statement re-treads ground covered by the first. It does not state that's *all* it does. So for me, the rest of your argument from that point does not follow and Twain has not made a mistake in his choice of words.

For example:

> Suppose the road were very long. Suppose it were to span several time zones. But I repeat myself. Simply, suppose it were to span several time zones.

The structure here does not imply that I can only be repeating myself if it's true that all "very long" roads "span several time zones". I believe that Twain intended the same structure. That is to say, he intended to state that "idiot" is a necessary *and obvious* property of members of Congress (just as a road spanning several time zones must be very long, there being no roads circling either pole). So stating someone is a member of Congress is to *repeat* that they are an idiot (as well as adding further information).

If Twain meant to say that repetition is all the second statement does, then he could have said, "but I merely repeat myself", which is more precise, and would suggest that it's the second statement that can be removed.

Comment: I didn't think about looking up the context and correct passing of the quote, uho stupid mistake. Good analysis!

Comment: @Voo: thanks for the question though, the research was worth it just to see "what you believed to be your faculties" ;-)

Comment: I find the whole quote not only entertaining, but also shockingly.. modern. I mean the sentiment could have been expressed today and it would be just as true.